# How to specify library paths for sonar-runner with C code

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I am trying to set up sonar-runner on a legacy code base. It seems to be working. However, I get several warnings like this:

> *WARN #include the file filename1.h could not be found at file:filename2.h. Please check your additional library configuration.*

I found a property I can possibly set in the sonar-project.properties file to point to all the library directories:

```
sonar.c.library.directories=/path/to/library/
```

My problem is, there are seriously about *50 directories* I will need to include to capture them all, and as far as I can tell, I need to type them all on a single line, comma-separated.

So, my question is,

## *is it worth it*?

Does sonar-runner need to find these dependencies to do an appropriate analysis?  Would I gain anything at all, or should I just let it be?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I have the same problem where we have tens of include paths.

Comment: No. We've been stalling with our implementation. Exploring maven or bamboo as the clients for Sonar instead of sonar-runner.